# html5 app cross-browser idea/structure

Tags: html, cordova

I am very new to web development, and i am trying to understand the structure for the flow for a html5 app using jquery mobile, to see whether i am doing Cross-origin resource sharing or not. I am basically just writing an app in html5, then going to package it in phonegap. I am hosting some php on a remote server and those php will make calls to the database and return the data through Ajax calls back to the app. 
   There is no error called if i run everything on my browser now, but if i package it with phonegap. Is that still going to be ok?

Comment: PhoneGap just creates a webview for you to run your HTML, CSS, JavaScript then opens an API for you to give you a step above what the browser alone can do with the device. If it runs on a browser, from what you've described, then it should work just fine. Wouldn't hurt to give it a try though just to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! Yer it works ok on my browser, but all the html doc with php are all within the same folder on a remote server, and the app would send request to the remote server, thats why i wondered, because in a browser environment, i enter the url to reach the html doc on the remote host. But when i package the app, the page is on my phone without reaching the host, thats why i wondered.

Comment: You'll just have to put the HTML docs in your PhoneGap project then make AJAX calls to your server to request data via the PHP files. You won't be able to execute PHP inside PhoneGap unfortunately.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks just 1 quick additional question. Does Infinite scroll from Jquery works in Jquery mobile?

Comment: I have no idea, never tried it. I'm guessing it would, but I don't know for sure. At work we use Ionic which has an infinite scroll directive. We started out with jQuery Mobile, but the performance was just not good at all. Ionic has been a huge step up.